# Jquery Nivo Slider Not working on homepage- Joomla 2.5

Tags: jquery, conflict, nivo-slider

I am new to Joomla and currently working on Joomla 2.5 to make a website http://www.aapkikundli.com/

My Nivo Slider was working fine till 2 days back and suddenly stopped working on homepage. However to my surprise, its working fine on other menu item

I suspected some jquery conflict and debugged the page using FireBug. I see 3 errors on my homepage now but not sure how to find and fix these files on Joomla 2.5!!

Your help is highly appreciated.!

Error from Chrome debugger are below

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9/jquery.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquerynoconflict.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( www.aapkikundli.com:314
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'wowSlider' script.js:22
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (OK)
```

How do I find these files and correct them?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the headsup. I have copied the errors from chrome debugger. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9/jquery.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquerynoconflict.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( www.aapkikundli.com:314
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'wowSlider' script.js:22
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (OK)

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple fix that could well work for you.
Disable one of them.. eg in nivo-slider/ppgallery conflict go to "slider" module ... advanced options and look for "Include jQuery Core" .. set to NO.
Your conflict should be resolved!